# Intel RAID Controller Rebuild RAID 5 While Windows Running

Tags: raid, raid5, intel

We have a RAID 5 array (3 drives) one of which failed this morning. If we take that drive out the system can boot into Windows Server '03 fine. Problem being we don't have anywhere to go if another drive fails. We have a good drive which we plugged into the failed one's slot while the server was in Intel RAID BIOS (not WIndows). Hit the "rebuild" button and it was slowly crunching.

We need this server to be back up and running so we booted into Windows and using the web-based manager we see that the drive is "rebuilding" .... but we're just not sure whether it actually is. It's been stuck at 1% for about half an hour. 99/250 gbs are used. Is this normal? Is the drive actually rebuilding while Windows is running?

Love to hear from someone who knows what they're doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be rebuilding while Windows is running, but rebuilding while data access is happening is a lot slower than rebuilding while no data access is happening.  Your RAID card vendor can give you more information.

Comment: Great thanks! I just noticed it went to 2%. It is muuuch slower.